# Issue with projection in SpringDataRest and @Lob attribute

Tags: spring-data-jpa, projection, spring-data-rest

I have an Entity Person :

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO, generator = "PERSON_SEQ")
private Integer idPerson;
private String lastName;
private String firstName;
@Lob
private byte[] picture;
```

**A repository**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Integer> {}
```

**A projection**

```
@Projection(name = "picture", types = { Person.class })
public interface ProjectionPicturePerson {
  byte[] getPicture();
```

}

When i used the projection : `..../persons/1?projection=picture`
i have this error

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>       Could not write content: [B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object; (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.["content"]->$Proxy109["picture"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: [B cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object; (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.["content"]->$Proxy109["picture"])

When i use a projection on a String, exemple lastName it works

```
@Projection(name = "lastName", types = { Person.class })
public interface ProjectionLastName {
   String getLastName();
}
```

When i don't use projection it works too

jackson serialize the image attribute

Is there a restriction on Blob ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug in `ProxyProjectionFactory`. I've filed and fixed [DATACMNS-722](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-722) for you scheduled to be in the upcoming services releases (mid next week).

Comment: Thanks Oliver for your quick response may be i see you for SpringOne